# How to read project file .csproj to compile only those .cs which includes in project

Tags: nant, csproj

How to read project file .csproj to compile only those class files (.cs) which includes in project. And ignore file which excluded from project.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? You can run MSBuild from `<exec/>` task and feed it with the `sln/csproj` files. And MSBuild will do the rest.